# Evaluate docstring in macros

Tags: elisp-macros, doc-strings

Macros like `defun` (or `defmacro` itself) have an optional `docstring` argument, but since they are macros and not functions, `docstring` isn't evaluated, but is taken as-is.

I need the `docstring` to be evaluated so that instead of something like this -

```el
"does a, then b, then c" ; b is hardcoded
```

I can put something like this instead -

```el
(concat "does a, then " (getenv "<some-shell-variable>") " , then c") ; b isn't hardcoded
```

Is it possible to do this without having to tweak the definitions of `defun` and `defmacro`?

By tweak, I don't mean overwriting the definitions, but writing new macros like `prefix-defun` and `prefix-defmacro` based on the existing definitions of `defun` and `demacro`, except, the docstring is evaluated by replacing all instances of `docstring` with `(eval docstring)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the doc string of any function, variable, or face to any string you want, whether (generated dynamically or not).

For a function `foo`, put the string you want on symbol `foo` as the value of property `function-documentation`:

```lisp
(defun foo () ; `foo' gets no doc string from this defun.
  (interactive)
  (message "FOOOOOOOO"))

(put 'foo 'function-documentation "I'm `foo'.") ; Give function `foo' a doc string.
(put 'foo 'function-documentation "I'm NEW `foo' doc.") ; Redefine the doc string.
```

Same thing for a defvar or defcustom - use symbol property `variable-documentation`:

```lisp
(defvar foo 42) ; Variable `foo' has no doc string.

(put 'foo 'variable-documentation "I'm `foo'.") ; Give var `foo' a doc string.
(put 'foo 'variable-documentation "I'm NEW `foo' .") ; Redefine the doc string.
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Documentation Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Documentation-Basics.html) and its subnodes.

Same thing for `defface`- use symbol property `variable-documentation`. But `defface` requires a doc string. You can nevertheless change it dynamically, as you can for a function or variable.

```lisp
(defface foo '((t :foreground "Red")) "0000") ; Doc string "0000".

(put 'foo 'face-documentation "11111") ; Change doc string to "1111".
```

Comment: Perfect, it works first of all and I really like this solution (symbol properties).

Answer (score 3):

```el
(defun foo ()
  (:documentation (concat "does a, then " (getenv "<some-shell-variable>") " , then c"))
  ...BODY...)
```

This is effectively a duplicate of [Is it possible to attach generated doc string to a lambda?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22625/is-it-possible-to-attach-generated-doc-string-to-a-lambda) except that question is very `lambda`-oriented, and so Stefan's answer doesn't point out that you can do the same thing with `defun`.

If you need the docstring to be `eval`'d on-demand (i.e. every time you request it), you can do that as well, but apparently not with `:documentation`.  Refer to my answer to the earlier question for some options for doing that.

Comment: ```*** Eval error ***  Symbol’s function definition is void: :documentation```, I tried it on `defmacro`. Both `:` and `documentation` are defined.

Comment: I've just tested, and `:documentation` works fine for `defmacro` in Emacs 27.1.  Alternatively, try using the `function-documentation` symbol property instead.

Comment: I *suspect* you put `(:documentation...)` into the macro's return value, though.   Don't do that.

Comment: Very strange, works perfectly when I run it in `ielm`, but if I put it in the init file, I get the error.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on there, then.  Personally I've always used `defalias` or the `function-documentation` symbol property to assign docstrings in atypical situations... The `:documentation` declaration had seemed to me like the best suggestion here, and had worked for me in cursory tests, but perhaps it has some quirks.

Comment: Considering `defun` and `defmacro` are ultimately using `defalias`, maybe a custom function object would do.